# Whmcs client logout button

Tags: logout, whmcs

I want to display a logout button for clients on whmcs and dont really know how to do it. I searched the internet but could not find a decent answer. Or maybe is a hook or some kind. 
Sorry if this is a repost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a method and a hook 
The hook looks like this

```
<a id="Menu-Hello_User-Logout" href="logout.php">{$LANG.logouttitle}</a>
```

And you can redirect the client after logout to what page u need